# Как заставить Console.WriteLine выводить double через точку а не запятую?

Tags: c#

Как заставить Console.WriteLine() выводить дробные числа через точку а не запятую?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045(v=vs.110).aspx `value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 1):

```
value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```